# TYPO3 indexed_search history

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x, tx-indexed-search

I'm using TYPO3 8 LTS-latest.

Is there a way to see a full history of all search queries performed by indexed_search?

I already searched for extension but a lot of them are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

And I am sure that all info is in the database itself. Look at the "index_stat_search" table. Use phpmyadmin. Or in the backend:

For Version 8 LTS use this:[image]

For Version 6.2 use this: [image]

Comment: yes thats true, that the statistic is available from the backend. But only per word, not per query. But thanks for the hint with phpmyadmin. there are the queries available. but sadly not a reasonable method for my customer.

Comment: you could do it via google analytics. do a costum call with Javascript everytime somebody hit the submit button on search page. (If you know Javascript, its a easy task)